# PHP - AJAX Process HTTP requests

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a form with x number of fields. When submitted, I want to;

1. get all input data, $var = $_POST['input']
2. validate input, (!empty($var) && is_numeric($var))
3. stick it in an array, array_push($myArray, $var)
4. generate URLS, $url.=$var
5. process the URL's without leaving the page

1 - 4 already done in php

Simply, im not familiar with Ajax. Been a decade since ive touched Javascript. Im not  sure if i should be using  javascript to do the whole process.  However, would prefer php to validate, Ajax to do http requests. Any sample code/sites available that passes php var's/array to Ajax to handle http requests?

Comment: any reason step 5 can't incorporate steps 1 - 4?

Comment: Hamish, step 5 im assuming is Ajax. From the examples ive looked at, havent found one that incorporates  1-5 using php and ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use some kind of format to pass data from the server to the client. I recommend [JSON](http://www.json.org/). PHP has [a built-in function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to encode an array into it, and JavaScript parses it natively.

As for the AJAX part itself, I recommend using a framework like JQuery. Makes it way simpler, and you don't have to deal with the different browsers yourself.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "yourpage.php",
  success: function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this-

```
$urlfield = explode(",", $urls);
```

You want to pass this array via jQuery AJAX, with this:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="hidden"  value="'.$urlfield.'">
  <input type="submit" id="processURL" class="Submit" name="ok" value="Send Reply"/>
</form>
```

And here's your jQuery:

```
$("#processURL").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var urlUsed = $("#urlfield").val();
        $.ajax( 
{ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: urlUsed, 
    data: ,// you can send some data
        beforeSend: function() {
                $("#processingURL").show(); //SOME FUNCTION TO SHOW URL PROCESSING
                },
            success: function() {
                alert("Success");
                }

         });    
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

// browser support code

```
 function getXMLHTTP()
  { //fuction to return the xml http object
            var xmlhttp = false;
            try {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                    try {
                        req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                    } catch (e1) {
                        xmlhttp = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            return xmlhttp;
        }
        // external file to linkup

         function secondpage(countryId) {

            var strURL = "secondpage.php?country=" + countryId;

            var req = getXMLHTTP();
            if (req) {

                req.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (req.readyState == 4) {
                        // only if "OK"

                        if (req.status == 200) {

                            document.getElementById('sid').innerHTML = req.responseText;
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById('sid').innerHTML = req.responseText;
                        }
                    }
                }
                req.open("GET", strURL, true);
                req.send(null);
            }
        }
```

in secondpage.php page ( i will get $_REQUEST['country'];)

Comment: Can you add some explanation to the code such that others can learn from it?

Comment: getXMLHTTP() use for broswer support and secondpage(countryId) for another page that part of like refresh and in your text box you will must be write onchange(this .value) also set span id=sid

Comment: Please add such explanation to your answer by editing it, not to the comment section